# Check python version build number

Tags: python, scripting, version

I need to check python version using a python script.
I know that `sys.version_info` and `platform.python_version()` are used for the purpose but the problem is that the value they return are :

`(2, 6, 6, 'final', 0)` and `2.6.6`

But I also need the the build number for my use-case which can be generated by `rpm -qa | grep python*` , e.g :

```
python-2.7.5-48.el7.x86_64
```

(build Number here being 48..)
Is there any way to do it using a python script ?

Comment: The minor version number is the second one. The `-64` is indicating a 64-bit architecture. If you want to get this part, you can go with @Rakesh answer.

Comment: I don't want the architecture number.. I've edited my question to remove the ambiguity.. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **[architecture](https://docs.python.org/2/library/platform.html#platform.architecture)** method in **[platform module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/platform.html#module-platform)**

```
import platform
print platform.python_version()
print platform.architecture()
print "Version: {}, Architecture: {}".format(platform.python_version(), platform.architecture()[0])
```

**Result:**

```
2.7.13
('32bit', 'WindowsPE')
Version: 2.7.13, Architecture: 32bit
```

Comment: I don't want the architecture number.. I've edited my question to remove the ambiguity.. :)